# Oracle trigger delete ip

Tags: oracle, triggers

Every time someone delete a user, I have to log who deleted the user. So a created a trigger that get ip address with SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'). However, the trigger insert 0.0.0.0 instead of the ip address of who actually deleted. How can i solve this?

Comment: How are you connected to your RDBMS server when testing ? Remotely or locally ?

Comment: Have you considered using UID instead of the IP address, or perhaps in addition to the IP address? An IP address by itself isn't a particularly strong way to identify someone.

Comment: The UID is a good ideia, but i still need the ip address.

Comment: At this point, you really should show us the code of your trigger to see if there is something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
select UTL_INADDR.get_host_address(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'HOST')) into ip_address from dual;
```

It uses a inner function of Oracle.

Tanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are very probably connected locally to your Oracle instance *without using the Oracle Net TCP/IP service*. In that case, `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS')` is `NULL`.

---

For example, when I connect to my Oracle instance through the LAN:

```
# using remote TCP connection:
sh$ sqlplus sylvain@oracle.lan.local
SQL> select coalesce(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'), 'NULL') from dual;

-> 10.1.2.3
```

When I do the same thing locally on the Oracle host:

```
# using IPC connection:
sh$ sqlplus sylvain  
SQL> select coalesce(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'), 'NULL') from dual;

-> NULL
```

**But** doing this will work as expected:

```
# using local TCP connection:
sh$ sqlplus sylvain@localhost
SQL> select coalesce(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'), 'NULL') from dual;

-> 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution didn`t work. The trigger still saving 0.0.0.0.